# Flattening a Nested JSON and output to HTML Table

Tags: html, json

i have this JSON string coming from the DACHSER API system :

```
{"shipments":[{"id":"A8225707231474437120","shipmentDate":"2021-10-28","forwarder":{"id":"60","partnerGLN":"5990034733003","names":["LIEGL & DACHSER KFT."],"addressInformation":{"city":"Pilisvörösvár","postalCode":"2085","countryCode":"HU"}},"shipmentWeight":{"weight":921.18,"unit":"kg"},"portOfDeparture":"LGW","portOfDestination":"MUC","consignor":{"id":"97165904","partnerGLN":"6174283362387","names":["Harry Potter"],"addressInformation":{"streets":["4 Privet Drive"],"city":"Little Whinging, Surrey","postalCode":"CB22 4RG","countryCode":"GB"}},"consignee":{"id":"68779302","partnerGLN":"8588788490809","names":["Ernie & Bert"],"addressInformation":{"streets":["Sesamstraße 9b"],"city":"Köln","postalCode":"50997","countryCode":"DE"}},"references":[{"code":"003","value":"OXOL5qaUnT"},{"code":"007","value":"3jVokinNYf"},{"code":"HAW","value":"wyf41593468"}],"status":[{"statusSequence":1,"id":"61116611867","statusDate":"2021-10-26T11:33:00","eventSetter":{"id":"250","partnerGLN":"4046823000007","names":["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],"addressInformation":{"city":"Hvidovre","postalCode":"2650","countryCode":"DK"}},"event":{"code":"K","extendedCode":"AS","description":"Non livré destinataire préavis"},"contactPerson":"Pumuckel c/o Eder","adviceDate":"2021-10-28"}]},{"id":"4355966256","shipmentDate":"2021-10-29","forwarder":{"id":"6","partnerGLN":"4022128000003","names":["DACHSER SE Logistikzentrum Allgäu"],"addressInformation":{"city":"Memmingen","postalCode":"87700","countryCode":"DE"}},"shipmentWeight":{"weight":460.48,"unit":"kg"},"consignor":{"id":"21946026","partnerGLN":"1290415437220","names":["Lucky Luke"],"addressInformation":{"streets":["Hot Stone Highway 47"],"city":"Texas City","postalCode":"77590","countryCode":"US"}},"consignee":{"id":"97165904","partnerGLN":"6174283362387","names":["Harry Potter"],"addressInformation":{"streets":["4 Privet Drive"],"city":"Little Whinging, Surrey","postalCode":"CB22 4RG","countryCode":"GB"}},"ssccs":["00335958250047964662"],"references":[{"code":"003","value":"HYtLv5pYb8"},{"code":"007","value":"osjY4448fd"},{"code":"SN","value":"4355966256"}],"status":[{"statusSequence":1,"id":"11391241896","statusDate":"2021-10-26T11:33:00","eventSetter":{"id":"250","partnerGLN":"4046823000007","names":["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],"addressInformation":{"city":"Hvidovre","postalCode":"2650","countryCode":"DK"}},"event":{"code":"R","extendedCode":"","description":"Mis en Livraison"},"ssccs":["00335958250047964662"]}]},{"id":"A2820280876091990016","shipmentDate":"2021-10-28","forwarder":{"id":"250","partnerGLN":"4046823000007","names":["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],"addressInformation":{"city":"Hvidovre","postalCode":"2650","countryCode":"DK"}},"shipmentWeight":{"weight":861.59,"unit":"kg"},"portOfDeparture":"MUC","portOfDestination":"CGC","consignor":{"id":"68779302","partnerGLN":"8588788490809","names":["Ernie & Bert"],"addressInformation":{"streets":["Sesamstraße 9b"],"city":"Köln","postalCode":"50997","countryCode":"DE"}},"consignee":{"id":"21269784","partnerGLN":"8340338594266","names":["Daisy Duck"],"addressInformation":{"streets":["Boulevard de Parc 12"],"city":"Coupvray","postalCode":"77700","countryCode":"FR"}},"references":[{"code":"003","value":"q9Fa6SXXFr"},{"code":"007","value":"FuEegxLYOv"},{"code":"HAW","value":"niw37194349"}],"status":[{"statusSequence":1,"id":"45310828399","statusDate":"2021-10-26T11:33:00","eventSetter":{"id":"250","partnerGLN":"4046823000007","names":["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],"addressInformation":{"city":"Hvidovre","postalCode":"2650","countryCode":"DK"}},"event":{"code":"R","extendedCode":"","description":"Mis en Livraison"}}]}]}
```

and, using javascript, this is the expected output i would like to get. As you can see the JSON levels are all concatenated in the table headers.
I can add more details if necessary, please ask in comments.
Actualy all examples found in stackoverflow are **not** doing it as i'm expecting.

https://jsfiddle.net/cetipabo/b34gqxmf/29/

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">shipments/id</th>
<th title="Field #2">shipments/shipmentDate</th>
<th title="Field #3">shipments/forwarder/id</th>
<th title="Field #4">shipments/forwarder/partnerGLN</th>
<th title="Field #5">shipments/forwarder/names/0</th>
<th title="Field #6">shipments/forwarder/addressInformation/city</th>
<th title="Field #7">shipments/forwarder/addressInformation/postalCode</th>
<th title="Field #8">shipments/forwarder/addressInformation/countryCode</th>
<th title="Field #9">shipments/shipmentWeight/weight</th>
<th title="Field #10">shipments/shipmentWeight/unit</th>
<th title="Field #11">shipments/portOfDeparture</th>
<th title="Field #12">shipments/portOfDestination</th>
<th title="Field #13">shipments/consignor/id</th>
<th title="Field #14">shipments/consignor/partnerGLN</th>
<th title="Field #15">shipments/consignor/names/0</th>
<th title="Field #16">shipments/consignor/addressInformation/streets/0</th>
<th title="Field #17">shipments/consignor/addressInformation/city</th>
<th title="Field #18">shipments/consignor/addressInformation/postalCode</th>
<th title="Field #19">shipments/consignor/addressInformation/countryCode</th>
<th title="Field #20">shipments/consignee/id</th>
<th title="Field #21">shipments/consignee/partnerGLN</th>
<th title="Field #22">shipments/consignee/names/0</th>
<th title="Field #23">shipments/consignee/addressInformation/streets/0</th>
<th title="Field #24">shipments/consignee/addressInformation/city</th>
<th title="Field #25">shipments/consignee/addressInformation/postalCode</th>
<th title="Field #26">shipments/consignee/addressInformation/countryCode</th>
<th title="Field #27">shipments/references/0/code</th>
<th title="Field #28">shipments/references/0/value</th>
<th title="Field #29">shipments/references/1/code</th>
<th title="Field #30">shipments/references/1/value</th>
<th title="Field #31">shipments/references/2/code</th>
<th title="Field #32">shipments/references/2/value</th>
<th title="Field #33">shipments/status/0/statusSequence</th>
<th title="Field #34">shipments/status/0/id</th>
<th title="Field #35">shipments/status/0/statusDate</th>
<th title="Field #36">shipments/status/0/eventSetter/id</th>
<th title="Field #37">shipments/status/0/eventSetter/partnerGLN</th>
<th title="Field #38">shipments/status/0/eventSetter/names/0</th>
<th title="Field #39">shipments/status/0/eventSetter/addressInformation/city</th>
<th title="Field #40">shipments/status/0/eventSetter/addressInformation/postalCode</th>
<th title="Field #41">shipments/status/0/eventSetter/addressInformation/countryCode</th>
<th title="Field #42">shipments/status/0/event/code</th>
<th title="Field #43">shipments/status/0/event/extendedCode</th>
<th title="Field #44">shipments/status/0/event/description</th>
<th title="Field #45">shipments/status/0/contactPerson</th>
<th title="Field #46">shipments/status/0/adviceDate</th>
<th title="Field #47">shipments/ssccs/0</th>
<th title="Field #48">shipments/status/0/ssccs/0</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>A8225707231474437120</td>
<td>2021-10-28</td>
<td align="right">60</td>
<td align="right">5990034733003</td>
<td>LIEGL &amp; DACHSER KFT.</td>
<td>Pilisvörösvár</td>
<td align="right">2085</td>
<td>HU</td>
<td align="right">921.18</td>
<td>kg</td>
<td>LGW</td>
<td>MUC</td>
<td align="right">97165904</td>
<td align="right">6174283362387</td>
<td>Harry Potter</td>
<td>4 Privet Drive</td>
<td>Little Whinging, Surrey</td>
<td>CB22 4RG</td>
<td>GB</td>
<td align="right">68779302</td>
<td align="right">8588788490809</td>
<td>Ernie &amp; Bert</td>
<td>Sesamstraße 9b</td>
<td>Köln</td>
<td>50997</td>
<td>DE</td>
<td align="right">003</td>
<td>OXOL5qaUnT</td>
<td align="right">007</td>
<td>3jVokinNYf</td>
<td>HAW</td>
<td>wyf41593468</td>
<td>1</td>
<td align="right">61116611867</td>
<td>2021-10-26T11:33:00</td>
<td align="right">250</td>
<td align="right">4046823000007</td>
<td>DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen</td>
<td>Hvidovre</td>
<td align="right">2650</td>
<td>DK</td>
<td>K</td>
<td>AS</td>
<td>Non livré destinataire préavis</td>
<td>Pumuckel c/o Eder</td>
<td>2021-10-28</td>
<td align="right"></td>
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4355966256</td>
<td>2021-10-29</td>
<td align="right">6</td>
<td align="right">4022128000003</td>
<td>DACHSER SE Logistikzentrum Allgäu</td>
<td>Memmingen</td>
<td align="right">87700</td>
<td>DE</td>
<td align="right">460.48</td>
<td>kg</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">21946026</td>
<td align="right">1290415437220</td>
<td>Lucky Luke</td>
<td>Hot Stone Highway 47</td>
<td>Texas City</td>
<td>77590</td>
<td>US</td>
<td align="right">97165904</td>
<td align="right">6174283362387</td>
<td>Harry Potter</td>
<td>4 Privet Drive</td>
<td>Little Whinging, Surrey</td>
<td>CB22 4RG</td>
<td>GB</td>
<td align="right">003</td>
<td>HYtLv5pYb8</td>
<td align="right">007</td>
<td>osjY4448fd</td>
<td>SN</td>
<td>4355966256</td>
<td>1</td>
<td align="right">11391241896</td>
<td>2021-10-26T11:33:00</td>
<td align="right">250</td>
<td align="right">4046823000007</td>
<td>DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen</td>
<td>Hvidovre</td>
<td align="right">2650</td>
<td>DK</td>
<td>R</td>
<td> </td>
<td>Mis en Livraison</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right">00335958250047964662</td>
<td align="right">00335958250047964662</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A2820280876091990016</td>
<td>2021-10-28</td>
<td align="right">250</td>
<td align="right">4046823000007</td>
<td>DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen</td>
<td>Hvidovre</td>
<td align="right">2650</td>
<td>DK</td>
<td align="right">861.59</td>
<td>kg</td>
<td>MUC</td>
<td>CGC</td>
<td align="right">68779302</td>
<td align="right">8588788490809</td>
<td>Ernie &amp; Bert</td>
<td>Sesamstraße 9b</td>
<td>Köln</td>
<td>50997</td>
<td>DE</td>
<td align="right">21269784</td>
<td align="right">8340338594266</td>
<td>Daisy Duck</td>
<td>Boulevard de Parc 12</td>
<td>Coupvray</td>
<td>77700</td>
<td>FR</td>
<td align="right">003</td>
<td>q9Fa6SXXFr</td>
<td align="right">007</td>
<td>FuEegxLYOv</td>
<td>HAW</td>
<td>niw37194349</td>
<td>1</td>
<td align="right">45310828399</td>
<td>2021-10-26T11:33:00</td>
<td align="right">250</td>
<td align="right">4046823000007</td>
<td>DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen</td>
<td>Hvidovre</td>
<td align="right">2650</td>
<td>DK</td>
<td>R</td>
<td> </td>
<td>Mis en Livraison</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td align="right"></td>
<td align="right"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to handle this using **datatables.net** in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cetipabo/b4es9dgm/1/)
But it is not a very nice way to do it as i have to manualy create the rows in the HTML part, also in the JS part. a way to automaticaly create the headers and fill the rows would be better.
So to get it working i have to modify the JSON by removing this **{"shipments":** and the latest **}**

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "A8225707231474437120",
  "shipmentDate": "2021-10-28",
  "forwarder": {
    "id": "60",
    "partnerGLN": "5990034733003",
    "names": ["LIEGL & DACHSER KFT."],
    "addressInformation": {
      "city": "Pilisvörösvár",
      "postalCode": "2085",
      "countryCode": "HU"
    }
  },
  "shipmentWeight": {
    "weight": 921.18,
    "unit": "kg"
  },
  "portOfDeparture": "LGW",
  "portOfDestination": "MUC",
  "consignor": {
    "id": "97165904",
    "partnerGLN": "6174283362387",
    "names": ["Harry Potter"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "streets": ["4 Privet Drive"],
      "city": "Little Whinging, Surrey",
      "postalCode": "CB22 4RG",
      "countryCode": "GB"
    }
  },
  "consignee": {
    "id": "68779302",
    "partnerGLN": "8588788490809",
    "names": ["Ernie & Bert"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "streets": ["Sesamstraße 9b"],
      "city": "Köln",
      "postalCode": "50997",
      "countryCode": "DE"
    }
  },
  "references": [{
    "code": "003",
    "value": "OXOL5qaUnT"
  }, {
    "code": "007",
    "value": "3jVokinNYf"
  }, {
    "code": "HAW",
    "value": "wyf41593468"
  }],
  "status": [{
    "statusSequence": 1,
    "id": "61116611867",
    "statusDate": "2021-10-26T11:33:00",
    "eventSetter": {
      "id": "250",
      "partnerGLN": "4046823000007",
      "names": ["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],
      "addressInformation": {
        "city": "Hvidovre",
        "postalCode": "2650",
        "countryCode": "DK"
      }
    },
    "event": {
      "code": "K",
      "extendedCode": "AS",
      "description": "Non livré destinataire préavis"
    },
    "contactPerson": "Pumuckel c/o Eder",
    "adviceDate": "2021-10-28"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "4355966256",
  "shipmentDate": "2021-10-29",
  "forwarder": {
    "id": "6",
    "partnerGLN": "4022128000003",
    "names": ["DACHSER SE Logistikzentrum Allgäu"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "city": "Memmingen",
      "postalCode": "87700",
      "countryCode": "DE"
    }
  },
  "shipmentWeight": {
    "weight": 460.48,
    "unit": "kg"
  },
  "consignor": {
    "id": "21946026",
    "partnerGLN": "1290415437220",
    "names": ["Lucky Luke"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "streets": ["Hot Stone Highway 47"],
      "city": "Texas City",
      "postalCode": "77590",
      "countryCode": "US"
    }
  },
  "consignee": {
    "id": "97165904",
    "partnerGLN": "6174283362387",
    "names": ["Harry Potter"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "streets": ["4 Privet Drive"],
      "city": "Little Whinging, Surrey",
      "postalCode": "CB22 4RG",
      "countryCode": "GB"
    }
  },
  "ssccs": ["00335958250047964662"],
  "references": [{
    "code": "003",
    "value": "HYtLv5pYb8"
  }, {
    "code": "007",
    "value": "osjY4448fd"
  }, {
    "code": "SN",
    "value": "4355966256"
  }],
  "status": [{
    "statusSequence": 1,
    "id": "11391241896",
    "statusDate": "2021-10-26T11:33:00",
    "eventSetter": {
      "id": "250",
      "partnerGLN": "4046823000007",
      "names": ["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],
      "addressInformation": {
        "city": "Hvidovre",
        "postalCode": "2650",
        "countryCode": "DK"
      }
    },
    "event": {
      "code": "R",
      "extendedCode": "",
      "description": "Mis en Livraison"
    },
    "ssccs": ["00335958250047964662"]
  }]
}, {
  "id": "A2820280876091990016",
  "shipmentDate": "2021-10-28",
  "forwarder": {
    "id": "250",
    "partnerGLN": "4046823000007",
    "names": ["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "city": "Hvidovre",
      "postalCode": "2650",
      "countryCode": "DK"
    }
  },
  "shipmentWeight": {
    "weight": 861.59,
    "unit": "kg"
  },
  "portOfDeparture": "MUC",
  "portOfDestination": "CGC",
  "consignor": {
    "id": "68779302",
    "partnerGLN": "8588788490809",
    "names": ["Ernie & Bert"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "streets": ["Sesamstraße 9b"],
      "city": "Köln",
      "postalCode": "50997",
      "countryCode": "DE"
    }
  },
  "consignee": {
    "id": "21269784",
    "partnerGLN": "8340338594266",
    "names": ["Daisy Duck"],
    "addressInformation": {
      "streets": ["Boulevard de Parc 12"],
      "city": "Coupvray",
      "postalCode": "77700",
      "countryCode": "FR"
    }
  },
  "references": [{
    "code": "003",
    "value": "q9Fa6SXXFr"
  }, {
    "code": "007",
    "value": "FuEegxLYOv"
  }, {
    "code": "HAW",
    "value": "niw37194349"
  }],
  "status": [{
    "statusSequence": 1,
    "id": "45310828399",
    "statusDate": "2021-10-26T11:33:00",
    "eventSetter": {
      "id": "250",
      "partnerGLN": "4046823000007",
      "names": ["DACHSER Denmark A/S Logistics Centre Copenhagen"],
      "addressInformation": {
        "city": "Hvidovre",
        "postalCode": "2650",
        "countryCode": "DK"
      }
    },
    "event": {
      "code": "R",
      "extendedCode": "",
      "description": "Mis en Livraison"
    }
  }]
}];

$('#myTable').DataTable({
  data: data,
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'shipmentDate' },
        { data: 'forwarder.id' },
        { data: 'forwarder.partnerGLN' },
        { data: 'forwarder.names' },
        { data: 'forwarder.addressInformation.city' },
        { data: 'forwarder.addressInformation.postalCode' },
        { data: 'forwarder.addressInformation.countryCode' },
        { data: 'shipmentWeight.weight' },
        { data: 'shipmentWeight.unit' },
        { data: 'consignor.id' },
        { data: 'consignor.partnerGLN' },
        { data: 'consignor.names' }
        
        ]

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>shipmentDate</th>
                <th>forwarder.id</th>
                <th>forwarder.partnerGLN</th>
                <th>forwarder.names</th>
                <th>forwarder.addressInformation.city</th>
                <th>forwarder.addressInformation.postalCode</th>
                <th>forwarder.addressInformation.countryCode</th>
                <th>weight</th>
                <th>unit</th>
                <th>consignor.id</th>
                <th>consignor.partnerGLN</th>
                <th>consignor.names</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</table>
```